# MySQL: Almacenar 365 días en binario, y hacer máscaras (AND) para búsquedas

Tags: java, mysql, string

Estoy haciendo un programa en Java que maneja una base de datos MySQL.
El problema es que guardo la disponibilidad de muchas salas de reuniones (digamos un número cercano al millón de salas) y esta disponibilidad se actualiza a diario (1 vez al día).

A la hora de almacenar esta disponibilidad, he creado un campo String que almacena en formato bit la disponibilidad 100011111010111...

Mi pregunta es si a la hora de buscar disponibilidad para varios días concreto, puedo aplicar un máscara AND en un campo String de la base de datos. De manera que en Java prepare esta máscara en String, y la consulta me devuelva todas las salas disponibles para unas fechas.

He pensado en almacenar la disponibilidad en otra tabla diferente, pero no quiero penalizar el tiempo de consulta, de ahí que acabara metiendo la disponibilidad como un campo String dentro de los datos de un sala.
He probado ha hacer INNER JOIN con segundas tablas, y al tener tantas salas, el tiempo de respuesta es muy lento.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Seguro que almacenar un millon de registros con un campo de 365 caracteres y tener que buscar en una posicion X de dicho campo es mas eficiente que hacer joins entre una o varias tablas? No veo clara la eficiencia de ese campo binario de disponibilidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de hacer la búsqueda es:

Para buscar disponibilidad los días 3, 4 y 5:

```
SELECT * FROM MITABLA T WHERE T.OCUPACION LIKE '__111___%'
```

Esta búsqueda supone que todos los campos ocupación empiezan en el día 1.

Dependiendo del número de registros y la complejidad de la búsqueda de días libres, tendrás que comprobar como de efectivo resulta en la práctica. Quizás resultaría más efectivo por meses para mantener el binario, ya que reducirías las posibles combinaciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Voy a probar la opción de LIKE y expresiones regulares, que no me había dado cuenta de esta opción.

Comment: No hay de que, espero que se ajuste a lo que buscabas. Solo tienes que controlar la posición al montar la cadena del like y puedes añadir tantas condiciones como quieras al select.